# How to ignore element order when diffing with XmlUnit

Tags: .net, xmlunit, xmldiff

I have XML in the following format:

```
<Root>
    <Elem1>
        <SubElem1>A</SubElem1>
        ...
    </Elem1>
    <Elem1>
        <SubElem1>B</SubElem1>
        ...
    </Elem1>
    <Elem2>
        ...
    </Elem2>
    ...
</Root>
```

I want to instruct XmlUnit's diff engine to ignore the order of ElemN elements, but only within their "group".

E.g.:

- If the second and the first Elem1 in the previous example would change order => equal
- If the Elem2 would become before Elem1 or in the middle of Elem1 => difference

Is there a way to achieve this result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is the job of `ElementSelector`. By default XMLUnit (2.x) compares elements in the order they appear in but you can influence which of the siblings are picked by using an `ElementSelector`.

I your case you seem to be happy with choosing elements in order unless they are named `Elem1`. For `Elem1` you'd like to choose pairs based on the text nested into the `SubElement1` child. One way to write such an `ElementSelector` could be

```
ElementSelectors.ConditionalBuilder()
    .WhenElementIsNamed("Elem1")
    .ThenUse(ElementSelectors.ByXPath("./SubElem1", ElementSelectors.ByNameAndText))
    .ElseUse(ElementSelectors.Default)
    .Build();
```

See the XMLUnit [user guide](https://github.com/xmlunit/user-guide/wiki/SelectingNodes) for more details and examples.

Comment: I had to adjust your answer to my needs, as I wanted to be all elements grouped together, not only Elem1 elements, but ElementSelector pointed me into the right direction.